# External Configuration of Spring boot and quartz.properties in apache camel

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I am implementing my code in Spring boot using Apache camel as middle layer and while setting the routes in camel i was using quartz2 component for this i wanted to use external quartz.properties file to override default quartz.properties file.Can someone please help me in this out.
I tried to implement using CommandLineRunner but i am getting exception like below
**org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulerApplication': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName' in value "${org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName}"**

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right you must be wanting to externalize your own quartz properties and try to use it in camel-quartz2 component.
create your customized entry in quartz.properties like below

```
quartz.uri=quartz://group/quartzScheduler?cron=0+05+21+?+*+*
```

Below is an example route

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
        super.configure();
        String externalService= PropertyParser.getInstance().getStringProperty(Key.Service);
        from(quartzEndpoint("sampleQuartz"))
                .to(externalService)
                .process(new Processor() {
                    public void process(Exchange e) throws Exception {
                        log.info("Before storing " + MessageHelper.extractBodyAsString(e.getIn()));
                        MyHelper.writeCLOBPut(e);
                        log.info("After storing " + MessageHelper.extractBodyAsString(e.getIn()));
                    }
                }).log("Stored in DB");
    }
```

Hope this helped

Comment: Thank you balaji for your response still i'm not clear like what is "sampleQuartz" in your code as it should be endpoint right.I'm using quartz2 component in my code.

Comment: Instead of writing the cron expression like this i have written a configurator method "quartzEndpoint" which accepts a name and fetches cron expression from database. In simple way u can write like this - from("quartz2://myGroup/myTimerName?cron=0+0/5+12-18+?+*+MON-FRI")